# Does system("cls") work fine in a virtual windows machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, virtual-machine

I have to submit a C++ project for marking soon, and I call `system("cls")` to clear the console a few times in my code. I know there are better methods but I just went for the easiest option.

As far as I am aware, `system("cls")` only works in Windows. The person who is going to mark my code will be using a virtual Windows machine in a computer with Mac. I have never used a virtual machine and I don't know much about them so I just want to make sure my code will run fine.

Comment: Probably.  But it can be affected by how the virtual machine is configured.   The only way to be sure is to test it.    More generally, however, if you have a "C++ project" that relies on clearing a screen, you're outside the realms of standard C++.    It is better to write your program so it only uses standard C++ features, unless the course (?) you're doing is explicitly about using some set of non-standard features.   That means avoiding GUI, clearing of screens, and a whole bunch on things.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We're indeed supposed to use standard C++, but we are grade for how visually appealing the console output is. It's an OOP course and I've chosen my project to be a chess game so I clear the screen everytime there's a new turn. I also change the colour of the output text using the ```Windows.h```. I don't know if this would be considered nonstandard too but I know its allowed within the 'course rules'

Comment: Yes, `Windows.h` is (well) windows specific - it is certainly not standard C++.  If your course explicitly allows/requires such things, then you can bet that your code will be assessed on a machine/setup where such things are known to work (too hard to administer the course, otherwise). Personally, I'd query the value of assessing the visual appeal of console output in an OOP course - the assessment criterion is not really related to the subject.  But, if the course is (say) "developing console games under windows" such an assessment makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will.  A Windows VM contains a regular Windows installation, running on a virtualised processor (under the control of the 'hypervisor').